# Iterate cluster centers for K means in Python

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have 4 columns of data. For these Xs, I need to pick 3 cluster centers randomly and find the cluster with least SSE. Why is it that the centers and inertia(SSE) turn out to be the same both with varying random states, and init=random parameter?

```
   Xvar=stud.iloc[:,1:5]

   #X1=np.random.randint(22,99,size=(3,4))

   kmeans1= KMeans(n_clusters=3, init='random', random_state=101)

   kmeans1.fit(Xvar)

   kmeans1.labels_ 

   kmeans1.cluster_centers_

   kmeans1.inertia_
```

Answer (score 0):

On too simple data, many different initial seeds will converge to the same result.

Plus, he default of `n_init` is 10 if I remember correctly, so if just 1 out of ten runs yields the same...

Comment: thanks, I think that was the problem. My data only had about 70 rows.